# Куки чужого домена

Tags: php, cookie

Здравствуйте.
Размещаем рекламу на форумах. Линки проходят через наш трекер. Так получается, что я вижу куки этого форума. Минимум сессионную. С их баннера идет редирект к ним (видимо тоже трекают), а затем к нам.
Стоит отметить, что происходит это, когда почему-то у нас в $_SERVER[SERVER_PROTOCOL] установлено HTTP 1.0.
Форум у них работает по https.
Как такое возможно?
Может в http 1.0 куки не привязываются к доменам. 
От браузера не зависит (юзер-агенты разные)
Пытался воспроизвести баг, но не получилось.
Хотя бы натолкните куда копать.

UPDATE. Пример такого юзера.
Всегда у такого бага [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0.
Еще странно, что Referer равен ссылке, на которую он пришел.
Может какие прокси кривые юзают.

```js
Datetime: 2015-04-04 08:36:36
IP: 142.54.161.130
Request: /GDW
Referer: http://our-shot-link.com/GDW
Country: US
City: Kansas City
Unique: No

SERVER:
(
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36 OPR/26.0.1656.24
    [HTTP_REFERER] => http://our-shot-link.com/GDW
    [HTTP_HOST] => our-shot-link.com
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => ALIENSID=a64bf2914d1e32cfe2c0dca7dc5f23a2
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/renmaster/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
    [SERVER_NAME] => our-shot-link.com
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 142.54.161.130
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/dev/our-shot-link.com/current/www
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/dev/our-shot-link.com/current/www/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 59079
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /GDW
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /GDW
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1428125796.03
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1428125796
)

COOKIE:
(
    [ALIENSID] => a64bf2914d1e32cfe2c0dca7dc5f23a2
)

REQUEST HEADERS:
(
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36 OPR/26.0.1656.24
    [Referer] => http://our-shot-link.com/GDW
    [Host] => our-shot-link.com
    [Cookie] => ALIENSID=a64bf2914d1e32cfe2c0dca7dc5f23a2
)

RESPONSE HEADERS:
(
    [Location] => http://destination-url.com/top
)
```

Comment: @aixx, Вижу их в переменной $_COOKIE. Там как минимум сессия их, потому что имя куки у них не стандартное PHPSESSID. Порой еще проскакивают гугловские __utm... Гугл-аналитики у нас нет. Даже сессию не устанавливаем. Мы просто пишем клик и отправляем юзера дальше. Отправляли через редирект с кодом 307, но HTTP 1.0 его не поддерживает, поэтому у нас сыпались ошибки. Вот мы и заметили это. Воспроизвести ошибку не смог. Запрос делал с HTTP 1.0, апач заставил отвечать тоже HTTP 1.0, но $_SERVER[SERVER_PROTOCOL] все равно равен 1.1. Подозреваю баг в протоколе 1.0, либо может у юзеров прокси какой.

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то неправильно поняли.

Куки шлет браузер, именно браузер не отдает куки куда не следует, поэтому искать "багу" в вашем апачи нет смысла. Проблемы просто не существует.

Может быть какие-то кривые боты неудачно имитируют куки, которых у вас быть не должно?

Comment: Я знаю, что за куки браузер отвечает. Копал старые спецификации - раньше действительно куки не были привязаны к доменам, но было это в 90-х.
Вариант ботов очень маловероятен: юзер-агенты разные (от IE 6, до разных версий хрома), ip совсем разные (US, РФ, UK и т.д.). Да и ловить этим ботам нечего. Мы просто записываем инфу о переходе для оценки эффективности рекламы.

Comment: Обновил вопрос примером юзера